# Change TextColor of disabled control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

How to change the color of text, when a control is disabled.I want to set different color when control is disabled in c# winforms.

Comment: Which type of control? Different controls behave different ways, and you'll need to handle these cases differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I had made the same mistake as Cody in the comments so corrected my answer.

It depends on which control it is.

For example, if it's a `TextBox` maybe you could make it `ReadOnly` instead of disabled. And for some other controls you might be able to do similar things to make them appear disabled without actually being disabled.

However, if you want to do it properly you need to make them Owner-draw or override the OnPaint event and draw the text yourself.

Comment: +1 for suggesting owner-drawn. This is the right way to solve this problem, and it is guaranteed to work for almost all of the common controls.

Comment: Neither Label, TextBox nor Button support owner-draw.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. In my head, I was equating owner-draw support with overriding the control's `Paint` event. I obviously realize this is not exactly the same thing, but it's how you'll need to handle labels, textboxes, and buttons, at minimum. The `ControlPaint` class can make this a little less painless.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it manually -- when you disable the control, just change the text colour too?

Comment: If the control in question is a `TextBox`, this will not work. You can only change its `BackColor` when it is disabled, not its `ForeColor` (i.e., the text color).

Answer (score 0):

If you have many controls, you can do this:

- attach your form OnChildAdded event
- in the event, use if ... is of type structure to determine control type
- depending on the control type, register proper OnEnabledChange event
- in the event, change text color appropriately

That way, you will have a piece of code that will work for all your forms and will gradually expand to use all the controls you need.

I'll provide some code if that's the way you want to go...