# How do you set text color of disabled form control button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to set the color of text in a control button to the same color of the control when it is disabled.
In other words... I don't want any text to show when button is disabled.

I don't know how else to phrase this question.

It is just important for the text not to appear when disabled.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you button is "button2". Then you can write this in button2's Enable_changed event.
You can select the event from the properties window.

```
private void button2_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((Button)sender).Enabled)
    {
       button2.Text = "Button";
    }
    else
    {
       button2.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Then whenever you want you can call as

```
button2.Enabled = true
```

Or you can set it to false. Tryout and respond. Bye

Comment: I gave this as best answer since it seems to be the best way to do what I asked. I don't think that you can change the text color of a disabled button... therefore just remove the text when disabled. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set visibiliy of control to false.

If you don't want to display text

1. you can hide button

   `button.Visible=false;`

**OR**

2. you can set text to empty

   `button.Text="";`

See also my question [Change TextColor of disabled control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374691/change-textcolor-of-disabled-control)

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer

Possible approaches other than setting the `Button1.ForeColor`:

- Set the `Text` property to `String.Empty`
- You can set an alternate image which can be displayed instead of the control when it is disabled.